# Kubernetes pod in minikube can't access a service

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service

I can't access a service from a pod, when I run the `curl serviceIP:port` command from my pod console, I get the following error:

```
root@strongswan-deployment-7bc4c96494-qmb46:/# curl -v 10.111.107.133:80
*   Trying 10.111.107.133:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 10.111.107.133 port 80 failed: Connection timed out
* Failed to connect to 10.111.107.133 port 80: Connection timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 10.111.107.133 port 80: Connection timed out
```

Here is my yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: strongswan-deployment
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: strongswan
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: strongswan
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: strongswan-container
          image: 192.168.39.1:5000/mystrongswan
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "--"]
          args: ["while true; do sleep 30; done;"]
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: dockerregcred

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: strongswan-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: strongswan
  ports:
    - port: 80  # Port exposed to the cluster
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80  # Port on which the pod listens
```

I tried with an Nginx pod and this time it works, I am able to connect to the Nginx service with the curl command.

I don't see where the problem comes from, since it works for the Nginx pod. What I did wrong?

I use minikube :

```
user@user-ThinkCentre-M91p:~/minikube$ minikube version
minikube version: v1.20.0
commit: c61663e942ec43b20e8e70839dcca52e44cd85ae
```

EDIT

My second pod yaml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: godart-deployment
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: godart
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: godart
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: godart-container
          image: 192.168.39.1:5000/mygodart
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9020
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: dockerregcred

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: godart-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: godart
  ports:
    - port: 9020  # Port exposed to the cluster
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9020  # Port on which the pod listens
```

The error :

```
[root@godart-deployment-648fb8757c-6mscv /]# curl -v 10.104.206.191:9020
* About to connect() to 10.104.206.191 port 9020 (#0)
*   Trying 10.104.206.191...
* Connection timed out
* Failed connect to 10.104.206.191:9020; Connection timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed connect to 10.104.206.191:9020; Connection timed out
```

the dockerfile :

```
FROM centos/systemd
ENV container docker
RUN yum -y update; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install systemd; yum clean all; \
(cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;
VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]

COPY /godart* /home


RUN yum install -y /home/GoDart-3.3-b10.el7.x86_64.rpm
RUN yum install -y /home/GoDartHmi-3.3-b10.el7.x86_64.rpm


CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

EDIT EDIT:

I solved my problem by adding a file that can respond to an http request, this is the file:

```
var http = require('http');

var handleRequest = function(request, response) {
  console.log('Received request for URL: ' + request.url);
  response.writeHead(200);
  response.end('Hello World!');
};
var www = http.createServer(handleRequest);
www.listen(9020, "0.0.0.0");
```

To make it work you must have a Node js environment installed.
Run the script with the command:`node filename.js`
And after that I am able to curl my services.

I don't really understand why it works now, does anyone have an explanation ?

Thank you

Comment: does your app(mystrongswan) listen port 80 like nginx ?

Comment: Not in particular, i've tried with different port number, it's the same problem

Comment: Hello, no unfortunately, I still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Your `strongswan-container` container is using `bash -c -- "while true; do sleep 30; done;"` as command.

The sleep command obviously does not listen to any port.

When you try to curl your service on port 80, a TCP connection is attempted towards the Pod on port 80, but since there is no such port listening in the Pod the connection attempt fails.

Comment: I am also triying with another pod, this time in the dockerfile I do not use the sleep command and yet the problem is the same, you can see more details in my edited post.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I added this command to my yaml file because if not my pod crash with the CrashLoopBackOff error, how canI fix this error without using the sleep command?

Comment: @ldin, Look at this [doc](https://sysdig.com/blog/debug-kubernetes-crashloopbackoff/) to understand CrashLoopBackOff. [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy) you can find additional info. Try to change restartPolicy for example to OnFailure or set the field `lastProbeTime` - Timestamp of when the Pod condition was last probed.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I fix this error without using the sleep command?

If I good understand your question I know 2 solutions of your problem. First you can understand how work [CrashLoopBackOff](https://sysdig.com/blog/debug-kubernetes-crashloopbackoff/). Then you can change [Container restart policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy). The most important field should be: `lastProbeTime`. This means `Timestamp of when the Pod condition was last probed.`

Second solution should be creating a [readiness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-readiness-probes). You can read more about it also [here](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/11/10/you-probably-need-liveness-and-readiness-probes#example_2__a_jobs_server__no_rest_api_).